# Eclipse: stack or pile for cut & copy & paste?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, stack, copy-paste

im just wondering as I couldn't find an answer on google (well, maybe Ive been trying the wrong keywords here >.< )... 
A thing I've always dreamt about was a **stack/pile cut feature** which remembers the - uhm, lets say - **10 last things I've cut** out or copied for pasting... Is there such a feature and if so, what is it called?

furthermore - is there a possibility to include your **own suggestions for autocompletion**? I'm not asking for much, just e.g. a while(true) suggestion instead of or extending the default ones...

Probably this should be migrated to superuser, but Im quite uncertain as this is somehow more programming related...
Thanks ever so much :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, the first part of the question I could answer myself: 
there are templates (Prefs -> Java (or whatever) -> Editor -> Templates) where you can add your custom tags :-) quite fancy this one! (always wanted to type "forever" and get a for(;;) loop)...

so, I did some digging and found that some people refer to that kind of feature as a **paste stack**...
for windows users [clipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) will do the trick for general use (as well as in an IDE). for the use in eclipse only the best I could come up with is [ViPlugIn](http://www.viplugin.com/viplugin/) which enables a **Vim-styled cut, copy & paste feature** which gives you some registers where you can store your "pastries" :-)
unfortunately this doesn't come for free (it's 20USD) - will work (AFAIK) without a license but you will be prompted a "missing license" each time you start up eclipse...

Comment: i use clipX, which is a very small en good working extension to your windows system

Comment: well, i found that programm as well - but Im not working on a windows machine :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first feature you've meantioned is often called "Multiple Clipboards." I've found [two](http://www.bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/MultiClipboard/toc.html) [plugins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/moreclipboard/) that do the job, but didn't like either. (IIRC neither could interact both ways with the system clipboard.)